# MPLAB X IDE failing to upload

Tags: mplab

Everything was working nicely then I tried to build and run some TCP/IP RTOS sample code. Since then I keep getting

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: RDDI_DAP_OPERATION_FAILED

and

> Program loaded with pack,SAMV71_DFP,4.4.78,Microchip
> Loading completed
> Connecting to programmer...
> The programmer could not be started: Could not connect to tool hardware: EdbgTool, com.microchip.mplab.mdbcore.AtmelIceScripting.AtmelIceScriptingBase

I've tried going back to projects that were working but same errors. The board is working fine - still seeing expected outputs over the COM channel.

Any tips how how to resolve this greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and you can solve it by emptying the chip. The problem came from the SAMV71 chip having the security bit set.

To clean the SAMV71 perform the following that the user manual indicates:

Page 27: "There is a 1x2 pin-header that is connected to the SAM V71 chip erase pin, PB12, and 3V3 marked ERASE. This header can be used to chip erase the SAM V71 by placing jumper on the header and toggle power to the board. After the power is toggled the jumper should be removed. Using the chip erase jumper may be the only way to erase a chip with the security bit set, and applications that immediately sets invalid clock options or goes into deep sleep without any wake-up sources enabled".

Source: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-42408-samv71-xplained-ultra_user-guide.pdf